# why need remove/add a NSView after it's reassigned to make it displayed

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview

I found that when I reassign a NSView(viewA aleardy added into superView) to another view(new viewB) , as below:

```
viewA = [[NSView alloc] init];
viewB = [[NSView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview viewA];
viewA = viewB;
```

viewB will not be updated into superView, event I try the following methods:

1)

```
[viewA setHidden: YES];
[viewA setHidded: NO];
```

2)
 `[viewA setNeedLayout: YES];`

Only to removew viewA and re-add it back to it's superview will work:

```
[viewA removeFromSuperView];
[self.view addSubview:viewA];
```

Could anybody help to explain why method 1) and 2) cannot update the rect of viewA ?

Comment: The code is confusing: `viewA` != `ViewA` != `veiwA`

Comment: @vadian, thanks for carefully check, it's typo, they are the same. sorry for that. I correct the wrong ones to viewA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add a view to the view hierarchy if you want to see it. `viewA = viewB;` makes variable `viewA` point to the same view as `viewB`, it doesn't add `viewB` to the view hierarchy.

Here's what your code does:

```
viewA = [[NSView alloc] init]; // viewA points to a new view(A)
viewB = [[NSView alloc] init]; // viewB points to a new view(B)
[self.view addSubview viewA]; // view(A) is added to the view hierarchy and will be displayed
viewA = viewB; // variable viewA points to view(B)

[viewA setHidden: YES]; // hides view(B)
[viewA setHidded: NO]; // unhides view(B), but view(B) isn't visible because it isn't part of the view hierarchy

[viewA setNeedLayout: YES]; // doesn't do anything, view(B) isn't visible because it isn't part of the view hierarchy

[viewA removeFromSuperView]; // doesn't do anything, view(B) isn't in a superview
[self.view addSubview:viewA]; // view(B) is added to the view hierarchy and will be displayed
```

Solution:
Add view(B) to the view hierarchy

```
viewA = [[NSView alloc] init]; // viewA points to a new view(A)
viewB = [[NSView alloc] init]; // viewB points to a new view(B)
[self.view addSubview viewA]; // view(A) is added to the view hierarchy and will be displayed
[self.view addSubview viewB]; // view(B) is added to the view hierarchy and will be displayed
```

Comment: Hi @Willeke, thanks for the step by step explanation.  My confusion on following 2 steps. 1)  viewA = viewB;       2) [self.view addSubview:viewA];  ;  in  2), you said viewB is added to the view hierarchy, but, What it adds is viewA. That's the most weird thing here. If viewA is same as viewB in 2), why in 1) , viewB cannot be loaded in UI automatically ?  Does that mean, variable's value and varialbe's UI display are 2 different panels, value assignment will not impact it's UI display , and step 1) is just a value assignment; only the view operation(step2) will make variable's UI displayed ?

Comment: The variables ` viewA` and `viewB` contain a pointer to (= the address of) a piece of memory where the view is located. When you do `viewA = viewB;`, you assign the address of view(B) to `viewA`. `viewA` now points to the memory of view(B). `viewA = viewB; ` doesn't do anything to the views itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Willeke, that makes sense and it's very clear now.